A Warning is showing while activating FlutterFire CLI
I am trying to activate FlutterFire CLI, but get:

Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated flutterfire_cli 1.0.0.

After Pasting dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli this command on cmd, then above warning is showing.
How to resolve it?

This means you need to add C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin into your System's environment path. It would be better if you restart the computer after adding it to the path variable.
For MacOS run: export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
